# Get attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I get an element by id, and I would like to know all attributes of the object.

I've using alerts for all this kind of stuff, is that the way its done in javascript?  In AS3 or whatever, I would place a break point, and investigate the object in the variables panel.

Second, if that is the way its done, how can I show ALL attributes, if I don't know what they are in advance, and show them in alert boxes?  Using jquery 1.5.  Thanks

Comment: [What is this for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Is your real problem that you need a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *"attributes"*, you mean the *"properties"* of the DOM node, then use...

```
console.dir(element);
```

...in Chrome's developer tools, or Firebug for Firefox.

This will allow you to expand the Object and fully inspect all of its properties, including the `.attributes` property.

Comment: @katspaugh: Yes it does, but `dir` is meant specifically for object property inspection.

Comment: Indeed, much better than `log`!

Comment: Ok, really helpful for future debugging. Thank you!  So then, a question on select tags.  Below is my code, this is a select object. 'value' shows up as a property in the console as I would expect, and yet my alert box shows 'undefined'.  Any ideas? Thanks

typeModuleId = $("#typeModuleId")
alert(typeModuleId.value)
console.dir(typeModuleId);
debugger;

Comment: @dt1000: It's because `$("#typeModuleId")` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element. To access the DOM element, do `$("#typeModuleId")[0].value`. Or you could use jQuery's `.val()` method. `$("#typeModuleId").val()`.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Sorry for all the questions, so is that returning an array of jquery objects?  So that is why I have to dig down to the first element?  Thanks!

Comment: @dt1000: It's an Array-like object. Not strictly an Array, but it does store the DOM elements at zero-based numeric indices, and it does have a `.length` property.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging with alerts will slowly drain your soul out through your nose.  Luckily, there is a better way.

The Javascript console in a modern browser (like Chrome or Safari, or with the Firefox extension Firebug) is awesome.

[image: console.log]

You can also set breakpoints in the script tab, or from the code via the `debugger` statement.    You can inspect globals and local variables in the scripts tab as well.  It's seriously awesome.

Checkout the chrome dev tools videos for way more awesome: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/videos.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

```
console.log(domElement);
```

That'll let you log statements and view the item as it exists after your script runs. Note though that Firebug treats the object as live, so changes to the object reflect in your log statement (you'll see the actual object in your log, not just a bunch of strings) at least, it did the last time I used it).

```
debugger;
```

That'll let you pause execution and analyze your object via watch window in Firebug or Chrome dev tools, or even in IE9's developer tools.

Comment: Note, that [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) provides many methods besides `log`.